# How to change state from a vuex store for all users

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Hello i'm using nuxt for a CRM, but i'have a problem with vuex. When i update a store it doesn't update for all users. I'm using the static deploiement on a vps and i use a REST API to communicate with my mysql database. And i use the module mode for vuex.

So for exemple my store looks like this :

*role/actions.js*

```js
export default {
  updateProsit: (context, value) => {
    context.commit('updateProsit', value)
    const equipe = (value % 11) + 1
    context.commit('updateEquipe', equipe)
  }
}
```

*role/getters.js*

```js
export default {
  role (state) {
    return state.role
  },
  numProsit (state) {
    return state.numProsit
  },
  equipe (state) {
    return state.equipe
  },
  currentEquipe (state) {
    const out = []

    state.role.forEach(function (item) {
      if (item.equipe === state.equipe) {
        out.push({
          role: 'Animateur',
          user: item.Animateur,
          avatar: 'https://luckysketch.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/chibi-siberian-husky.png'
        })
        out.push({
          role: 'Secretaire',
          user: item.Secretaire,
          avatar: 'https://luckysketch.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/chibi-siberian-husky.png'
        })
        out.push({
          role: 'Scribe',
          user: item.Scribe,
          avatar: 'https://luckysketch.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/chibi-siberian-husky.png'
        })
        out.push({
          role: 'Gestionaire',
          user: item.Gestionaire,
          avatar: 'https://luckysketch.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/chibi-siberian-husky.png'
        })
      }
    })

    return out
  }
}
```

*role/mutations.js*

```js
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
  updateProsit: (state, data) => state.numProsit = data,
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
  updateEquipe: (state, data) => state.equipe = data
}
```

*role/state.js*

```js
export default () => ({
  role: [
    {
      equipe: 1,
      Animateur: 'Gurvan',
      Secretaire: 'Francois',
      Scribe: 'Benjamin',
      Gestionaire: 'Kevkev'
    },
    {
      equipe: 2,
      Animateur: 'Kevkev',
      Secretaire: 'Remi',
      Scribe: 'Louis',
      Gestionaire: 'Francois'
    },
    {
      equipe: 3,
      Animateur: 'Francois',
      Secretaire: 'Julien',
      Scribe: 'Gwn',
      Gestionaire: 'Mmouky'
    },
    {
      equipe: 4,
      Animateur: 'Remi',
      Secretaire: 'Benjamin',
      Scribe: 'Armand',
      Gestionaire: 'Gurvan'
    },
    {
      equipe: 5,
      Animateur: 'Pauline',
      Secretaire: 'Gwn',
      Scribe: 'Mmouky',
      Gestionaire: 'Armand'
    },
    {
      equipe: 6,
      Animateur: 'Benjamin',
      Secretaire: 'Kevkev',
      Scribe: 'Julien',
      Gestionaire: 'Gwn'
    },
    {
      equipe: 7,
      Animateur: 'Mmouky',
      Secretaire: 'Gurvan',
      Scribe: 'Remi',
      Gestionaire: 'Pauline'
    },
    {
      equipe: 8,
      Animateur: 'Gwn',
      Secretaire: 'Pauline',
      Scribe: 'Francois',
      Gestionaire: 'Louis'
    },
    {
      equipe: 9,
      Animateur: 'Louis',
      Secretaire: 'Mmouky',
      Scribe: 'Kevkev',
      Gestionaire: 'Remi'
    },
    {
      equipe: 10,
      Animateur: 'Julien',
      Secretaire: 'Armand',
      Scribe: 'Gurvan',
      Gestionaire: 'Benjamin'
    },
    {
      equipe: 11,
      Animateur: 'Armand',
      Secretaire: 'Louis',
      Scribe: 'Pauline',
      Gestionaire: 'Julien'
    }
  ],
  currentEquipe: [],
  numProsit: 13,
  equipe: 3
})
```

So the point is when i update `NumProsit` it update `equipe` and then the `currentEquipe` get the corresponding equipe from role. And it works but only for me the others users do not see the update. 
So i was wondering if i needed to use my database to store these data or if a solution exist with vuex.

I probably misunderstood some point with vuex.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is only meant for local client side state. If you need to update the local state other users then you need to incorporate web-sockets. I would recommend [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Thank you, that's what i tought i've found a solution but i will keep yours in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuex is for managing app state in the browser for a single user. 
What you are looking to do is to change the state across multiple users. This would require you leverage a websocket implementation. This would allow your backend to broadcast changes to your client side app.

Comment: Yep thank you, i've choose to change things a little bit and use my database, but i'll keep your solution in mind.